# public string blaBla { get; set; } in python

Tags: c#, python, class, methods, equivalent

Consider the following example to understand better my question:

```
public class ClassName 
{
    public ClassName { }

    public string Val { get; set; }

    ...
}

ClassName cn = new ClassName();

cn.Val = "Hi StackOverflow!!";
```

What would be the equivalent of this code in python?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can easily add members to any Python object as show in other answers.  For more complicated get/set methods like in C#, see the [property](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) builtin:

```
class Foo(object):
   def __init__(self):
      self._x = 0

   def _get_x(self):
      return self._x

   def _set_x(self, x):
      self._x = x

   def _del_x(self):
      del self._x

   x = property(_get_x, _set_x, _del_x, "the x property")
```

Answer (score 3):

Python does not have getters and setters in this sense. The following code is the equivalent to the above code:

```
class ClassName:
    pass

cn = ClassName()

cn.val = "Hi StackOverflow!!"
```

Notice that python has no mention of getters/setters; you don't even need to declare `val` until you set it. To make custom getters/setters you could do for example this:

```
class ClassName:
    _val = "" # members preceded with an underscore are considered private, although this isn't enforced by the interpreter

    def set_val(self, new_val):
        self._val = new_val

    def get_val(self):
        return self._val
```

Comment: Just to add to this you can also use property() or the property decorator as described here - http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property

Answer (score 0):

```
class a:
 pass    //you need not to declare val
x=a();
x.val="hi all";
```